# Searching for videos with titles beginning with word

Tags: facebook, search, video, search-engine

I'm trying to find a video from Vimeo I shared a few years ago on Facebook. The title of the video began with "Like" and it was about a virtual relationship which eventually turned "analog".

Is there a Facebook app which shows video Links shared by you?  The two I found no longer work.

The Facebook search engine doesn't reveal any answers; it's incomplete.

Or is there a short film search engine?  The one I found on the net doesn't have it. And it isn't http://m.imdb.com/title/tt2227088/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I [asked](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-search-for-videos-with-titles-beginning-with-a-specific-word) on Quora and got the answer from a Vimeo community manager:

> LiKE by SwitchBack Entertainment - https://vimeo.com/22663134
>
> > This is our entry for the 2011 72hr Filmmaker Showdown at the Telus World Ski & Snowboard Festival in Whistler, BC.
> >
> > 50 teams had 72 hours to fully produce a 3 -5 minute film. As the competition started each team was given a prop which had to appear in their film for at least 5 seconds. This year's prop was a green apple.

Comment: And when that link no longer works, this answer has no value. Even then, it's not shared how it was found. Just "sleuthing". So, while you got what you were looking for, there's no value here for anyone who comes along who has the same problem as you.

Comment: Yes I tried to get more answers out of the community manager but she didn't respond. It has value as the general description of the question is there and the right answer; although yes it's very specific to my case. And also it links to another question site where someone else could ask to get answers.

Comment: I've added in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You could go to the [Activity Log](https://www.facebook.com/me/allactivity) and click "[Your Posts](https://www.facebook.com/me/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=cluster_11)". Then search for "Video".

That'll probably bring back a lot, but it'll narrow it down from *everything* you've ever posted.

It's easy to limit Google searches to a particular domain (e.g., `site:vimeo.com`) but, unfortunately, "like" is such a common word it'll be useless in a search.

Comment: Maybe its didn't share it on facebook. I thought i did though.